# Facebook C# using results from multiquery

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am using a multiquery to get friends checkins.  I have the query returning the data as expected but what I want to do is to create a DataTable that contains elements from each of the queries.  I only 3 results but there are at least one hundred in the data.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong other than I know my loop is incorrect.  Ironically, or not, 3 is the number of queries.  I;m sure it is my foreach but I'm not sure what I should be looping on.  Please help.

```
dynamic resultCheckins = fb.Get("fql",
   new
   {
       q = new
       {
           friends_checkins = "SELECT author_uid, coords, timestamp, page_id, message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
           users = "SELECT uid, name, pic_small from user where uid IN (SELECT author_uid FROM #friends_checkins)",
           resultCheckins = "SELECT page_id, name, description from place where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #friends_checkins)",
       }
   });

JObject resultCheckinsJson = JObject.Parse(resultCheckins.ToString());
DataTable CheckIn = new DataTable();
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Friend", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Picture", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Link", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Place", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Coords", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("When", typeof(string)));
CheckIn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(string)));

int thiscounter = 0;
foreach (var row in resultCheckinsJson["data"].Children())
{
    string placename = resultCheckins.data[1].fql_result_set[thiscounter].name.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    string NavigateURL = "http://facebook.com/" + resultCheckins.data[1].fql_result_set[thiscounter].page_id.ToString().Replace("\"", "");

    DataRow CheckInRow = CheckIn.NewRow();
    CheckInRow["Friend"] = resultCheckins.data[2].fql_result_set[thiscounter].name;
    CheckInRow["Picture"] = resultCheckins.data[2].fql_result_set[thiscounter].pic_small;
    CheckInRow["Link"] = ResolveUrl(NavigateURL);
    CheckInRow["Place"] = resultCheckins.data[1].fql_result_set[thiscounter].name.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    CheckInRow["Coords"] = resultCheckins.data[0].fql_result_set[thiscounter].coords.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    DateTime dtDateTime =  dtDateTime.AddSeconds(resultCheckins.data[0].fql_result_set[thiscounter].timestamp).ToLocalTime();
    CheckInRow["When"] = dtDateTime.ToString();
    CheckInRow["Message"] = resultCheckins.data[0].fql_result_set[thiscounter].message.ToString();
    CheckIn.Rows.Add(CheckInRow);
    thiscounter++;
}
```

Comment: I've never worked with the Facebook API, but the guy in the following question fetched the result with another logic (I helped him with my answer also). Please, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623714/convert-fql-results-to-custom-class/11624318#11624318

Comment: Can you post the JSon you are getting back (with personal information obfuscated, or course :-)). Would help to answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
foreach (var row in resultCheckinsJson["data"].Children())
```

To:

foreach (dynamic row in resultCheckinsJson.data)

Then get the properties like this:

```
row.name
```