# Convert FQL Results to custom class?

Tags: c#, linq, facebook-c#-sdk

I am a fairly new C# programmer and am getting stuck on trying to convert FQL results into a custom class...for example, I am doing the following, but it seems like a lot of steps...I was just returning a datatable, but wanted the result to be strongly typed class collection. I'd appreciate any insights. I'm open to other ways of achieving similar results as well.

Thanks,
Chad

```
public class FacebookFriends
{
    public string FriendID { get; set; }
    public string FriendName { get; set; }
    public string PicURLSquare { get; set; }
    public string ProfileLink { get; set; }

    //Gets your FB friends that are NOT currently using this application so you can invite them
    public IEnumerable<FacebookFriends> GetFriendsNotUsingApp()
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, link FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND NOT is_app_user";

        FacebookSDKInterface objFQL = new FacebookSDKInterface();
        dynamic objFNU = objFQL.FBFQL(strQuery);

        //Construct the new, formated, merged datatable to store the results the way we want them   
        DataTable dtFriendsNotUsingApp = new DataTable();    
        dtFriendsNotUsingApp.Columns.Add("FriendID");
        dtFriendsNotUsingApp.Columns.Add("FriendName");
        dtFriendsNotUsingApp.Columns.Add("PicURLSquare");
        dtFriendsNotUsingApp.Columns.Add("Link");

        if (objFQL != null)
        {
            foreach (dynamic row in objFNU.data)
            {
                //Add New DataRow to new DataTable
                DataRow drRow = dtFriendsNotUsingApp.NewRow();

                //Get various values from original JSON Friend List returned
                drRow["FriendID"] = row.uid;
                drRow["FriendName"] = row.name;
                drRow["PicURLSquare"] = row.pic_square;
                drRow["Link"] = row.link;

                //Add New Row to New Resulting Data Table
                dtFriendsNotUsingApp.Rows.Add(drRow);
            }

            dtFriendsNotUsingApp.DefaultView.Sort = "FriendName";
        }

        IEnumerable<FacebookFriends> objFriendsListCollection = null;

        var toLinq = from list in dtFriendsNotUsingApp.AsEnumerable()
                     select new FacebookFriends
                     {
                         FriendID = list["FriendID"].ToString(),
                         FriendName = list["FriendName"].ToString(),
                         PicURLSquare = list["PicURLSquare"].ToString(),
                         ProfileLink = list["ProfileLink"].ToString()
                     };

        objFriendsListCollection = toLinq.OrderByDescending(p => p.FriendName);

        return objFriendsListCollection;

    } //Get FB Friends not already using this app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this may help.

**1st**: I've never used the Facebook API, so I'm just using your code as an example.

**2nd**: As the method is inside the class, I've changed it to `static`. This way, you can use it by simply calling `FacebookFriends.GetFriendsNotUsingApp()`, instead of `new FacebookFriends().GetFriendsNotUsingApp()`.

**3rd** The code:

```
    public class FacebookFriends
    {
        public string FriendID { get; set; }
        public string FriendName { get; set; }
        public string PicURLSquare { get; set; }
        public string ProfileLink { get; set; }

        //Gets your FB friends that are NOT currently using this application so you can invite them
        public static IEnumerable<FacebookFriends> GetFriendsNotUsingApp()
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, link FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND NOT is_app_user";

            FacebookSDKInterface objFQL = new FacebookSDKInterface();
            dynamic objFNU = objFQL.FBFQL(strQuery);

            List<FacebookFriends> friendsToReturn = new List<FacebookFriends>();

            if (objFQL != null)
            {
                foreach (dynamic row in objFNU.data)
                {
                    friendsToReturn.Add(new FacebookFriends()
                        {
                            FriendID = row.uid,
                            FriendName = row.name,
                            PicURLSquare = row.pic_square,
                            ProfileLink = row.link
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            return friendsToReturn;
        } //Get FB Friends not already using this app
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks Andre...and for the additional pointers as well!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Facebook API or FQL as well, but by looking at your code `objFNU.data` appears to implement `IEnumerable`, hence you can use LINQ extension methods directly with it:

```
public class FacebookFriends
{
    public string FriendID { get; set; }
    public string FriendName { get; set; }
    public string PicURLSquare { get; set; }
    public string ProfileLink { get; set; }

    //Gets your FB friends that are NOT currently using this application so you can invite them
    public static IEnumerable<FacebookFriends> GetFriendsNotUsingApp()
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, link FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND NOT is_app_user";

        FacebookSDKInterface objFQL = new FacebookSDKInterface();
        dynamic objFNU = objFQL.FBFQL(strQuery);

        if (objFQL != null) // shouldn't you check objFNU for being null here instead?
        {
            IEnumerable<dynamic> objFNUdata = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)objFNU.data; // explicit cast might not be necessary
            return objFNUdata.Select(row => new FacebookFriends()
                {
                    FriendID = row.uid,
                    FriendName = row.name,
                    PicURLSquare = row.pic_square,
                    ProfileLink = row.link
                }).OrderByDescending(p => p.FriendName);
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<FacebookFriends>();
        }
    } //Get FB Friends not already using this app
}
```

Comment: Thank you Damir for your response. I like this as it is clean and avoids for each loops which I'd think would have better performance. However, this gives the error: "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type" at both lamda lines (p => and row =>). Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChadRichardson Yes, it slipped my mind that you can't use lambda expressions with dynamically typed variables. It should be enough to cast your `dynamic` to an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. I already edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks Damir...I'd really like to go this route, but that doesn't work either. It gives a "IEnumerable<dynamic> does not contain a definition for data" with regards to the "objFNU.data.Select" statement. Know anyway around that?

Comment: @ChadRichardson Sorry about that, `objFNU.data` is an `IEnumerable`, not `objFNU`. I edited the code above again. Any better now?

Comment: Hey Damir, well, the code compiles, but at runtime, I get an error: {"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"}. Not sure what that means in this scope. When I view the value of objFNUdata, everything looks correct...there are no null values. So I can't figure out why it is stating this error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I figured it out...see answer I posted. Thanks Damir for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked best for me. Thanks to both, and especially @DarmirArh for all his help in getting this to work.

```
try
        {
            FacebookSDKInterface objFQL = new FacebookSDKInterface();
            dynamic objFNU = objFQL.FBFQL(strQuery);

            if (objFNU != null) // shouldn't you check objFNU for being null here instead?
            {
               IEnumerable<dynamic> objFNUdata = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)objFNU.data; // explicit cast might not be necessary
               IEnumerable<FacebookFriends> objMyFriends =
               from row in objFNUdata
               select new FacebookFriends()
               {
                   FriendID = row.uid,
                   FriendName = row.name,
                   PicURLSquare = row.pic_square,
                   ProfileLink = row.profile_url
               };

               objMyFriends = objMyFriends.OrderBy(p => p.FriendName);
               return objMyFriends;
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<FacebookFriends>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<FacebookFriends>();
        }
```